# Is there a way to test Azure B2C custom policies locally without uploading XML files to the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to test Azure B2C custom policies locally without uploading XML files to the Azure Portal under the B2C > Identity Experience Framework blade?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported.

You can validate the content of the policy definitions using [this XML schema](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd) but you can't test the execution of them.

You can debug the policy executions by [sending logs to Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom).